# Why does Page Down/Up using Fn+Down/Up not work on some applications?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I have a Macbook. Fn+Down/Up keys work as Page Down/Up in some applications but not in every application.

Some critical applications that this key binding don't work are Firefox and IntelliJ Idea.

Is there any way to make this key binding work in those applications?

Comment: I guess, page up/down works with an external keyboard having these keys?

Comment: Firefox does not use normal Cocoa key bindings c.f. ctrl-T and IntelliJ is a Java program So in both cases this is a bug as the authors have not done the extra work to do this.

Comment: @Mark, so why does it work for me then? at least for FF, I could not test the IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested in my FF ver. 29.0.1 with <kbd>Fn</kbd> arrow UP and Down and it works on my MBA 10.9.3

[More information on FF shortcuts.](http://mzl.la/MbezM6)

For FF you can also [customize](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/) the shortcuts.

I do not have the IntelliJ to test.

Some applications use the own keyboard shortcuts and override OS X settings.